# Get Class By String Name In Android To Avoid Repeating Myself

Tags: android, kotlin, dry, data-class

So in my code, I'm getting a list of strings, which correspond to movie genres in an enum.  I'm then getting a metadata file, and going through each of those genres, seeing if the date the server updated that genre is newer than the date I retrieved those movies and stored them in the database.  Long story short, the metadata file has classes for each of the genres, and I'm doing a TON of repeating myself, simply for the fact that I can't think of how to programtically let my app know that, for instance, if you're evaluating the genre ACTION you should look at the member variable metadata.action.  Here's my code, I've truncated it but there are a couple dozen genres.

**TwMetadata**

```
data class TwMetadata (

        @SerializedName("action") var action : Action,
        @SerializedName("adventure") var adventure : Adventure,
        @SerializedName("animation") var animation : Animation,
        @SerializedName("comedy") var comedy : Comedy,

)
```

In the following code, I've taken the list of strings I've pulled from the server, converted them into genre enums, and am checking the date last updated in the sharedpreferences metadata  file (spObj), vs the date last updated in the newly pulled metadata file(metadata.value).  If there is new data, I'm changing the date in the sharedpreferences metadata file, which I commit at the end of this completable.  Then I'm sending it to a function which either pulls the data from the database or the web, depending on the value of the boolean i'm sending it.  Ideally I'd be able to get rid of this entire 'when' block and just run a single function on each genre, but for that to work they'd need to know what class they correspond to in the metadata file.

```
  private fun checkGenreDate(genreList: MutableList<GENRE>) : Completable {
    return Completable.create { emitter ->

      var getNew = json.isNullOrEmpty()

      genreList.forEach {
        when (it) {
          GENRE.NULL -> {
          }
          GENRE.ACTION -> {
            if (spObj.action.updated < metadata.value!!.action.updated) {
              getNew = true
              spObj.action = metadata.value!!.action
            }
            loadFromTwApi(it, getNew)
          }
          GENRE.ADVENTURE -> {
            if (spObj.adventure.updated < metadata.value!!.adventure.updated) {
              getNew = true
              spObj.adventure = metadata.value!!.adventure
            }
            loadFromTwApi(it, getNew)
          }
          GENRE.ANIMATION -> {
            if (spObj.animation.updated < metadata.value!!.animation.updated) {
              getNew = true
              spObj.animation = metadata.value!!.animation

            }
            loadFromTwApi(it, getNew)
          }
          GENRE.COMEDY -> {
            if (spObj.comedy.updated < metadata.value!!.comedy.updated) {
              getNew = true
              spObj.comedy = metadata.value!!.comedy
            }
            loadFromTwApi(it, getNew)
          }
          GENRE.RANDOM -> {
          }
          GENRE.THEATER -> {
            loadTheaterData()
          }
        }
      }
      emitter.onComplete()
    }
  }
```

**my enum class**

```
enum class GENRE {
  NULL,
  ACTION,
  ADVENTURE,
  ANIMATION,
  COMEDY,
  RANDOM,
  THEATER;

  companion object {
    fun getGenreByName(name: String) = try {
      (name.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()))
    } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
      null
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a generic [sealed class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/sealed-classes.html) with abstract metadata get and set methods, and a static lookup method included on the sealed class. Pretty much Kotlin magic for turning enums into a class hierarchy so you can both share and enforce functionality amongst them.

So for just Action and Adventure, here's a function `updateAllGenres` which will update all the metadata.

```
fun updateAllGenres( spObj: TwMetadata, metadata: MetadataFile ) {
    Genre.forEach {
        it.maybeUpdateSharedMetadata( spObj, metadata )
    }
}

sealed class Genre < T : GenreMetadata > {
    companion object {
        fun forEach( callback: ( Genre < * > ) -> Unit ) {
            Genre::class.sealedSubclasses.forEach {
                callback( it.objectInstance as Genre < * > )
            }
        }
    }

    fun maybeUpdateSharedMetadata( spObj: TwMetadata, metadata: MetadataFile ): Boolean {
        val genreMetadataInFile = getGenreMetadata( metadata.value!! )
        return getGenreMetadata( spObj ).updated < genreMetadataInFile.updated
            .also { setGenreMetadataInDictionary( spObj, genreMetadataInFile )
        }
    }

    protected abstract fun getGenreMetadata( metadata: TwMetadata ): T
    protected abstract fun setGenreMetadataInDictionary( metadata: TwMetadata, genreMetadata: T )
}

object ActionGenre : Genre < Action >() {
    override fun getGenreMetadata( metadata: TwMetadata ): Action {
        return metadata.action
    }

    override fun setGenreMetadataInDictionary( metadata: TwMetadata, genreMetadata: Action ) {
        metadata.action = genreMetadata
    }
}

object AdventureGenre : Genre < Adventure >() {
    override fun getGenreMetadata( metadata: TwMetadata ): Adventure {
        return metadata.adventure
    }

    override fun setGenreMetadataInDictionary( metadata: TwMetadata, genreMetadata: Adventure ) {
        metadata.adventure = genreMetadata
    }
}
```

A couple more tweaks are needed to get exactly your function, but I'm sure you get the idea. Also, you might want to go further than this and look at combining the sealed subclasses and the classes `Action`, `Adventure` etc that hold the metadata, but that's a bit more work.

For reference the interfaces in the above are:

```
interface Action : GenreMetadata {}
interface Adventure : GenreMetadata {}

interface GenreMetadata {
    val updated: Long
}

interface TwMetadata {
    var action: Action
    var adventure: Adventure
}

interface MetadataFile {
    val value: TwMetadata?
}
```